# how can I overcome "ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras-layer

I am new to Keras and CNN. I am working on an assignment to build a CNN for predicting face emotions. I built the model as per the assignment but while compiling the model I get "ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible". Can someone help me how to resolve this?

Pasting my code below for reference:

'''

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 64, kernel_size = 5,input_shape = (48,48,1)))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=5,strides=(1, 1), padding='valid'))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=1, padding='valid'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size = 5))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 128, kernel_size=5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size = 5))
model.add(Conv2D(filters = 256, kernel_size=5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(7,activation='softmax'))
```

'''
'Then tried to compile'
'''

```
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
history = model.fit(input_array, output_array, batch_size = 64, epochs= 20, validation_split=0.10,)
```

'''
'This gives the error'
'ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible'
'I am using google colab for this'

Comment: What are the shapes of `input_array` and `output_array`. Also edit your text and put the whole error traceback.

Comment: I think it is better if you give us the full traceback :)

Comment: You are probably trying to use numerical class labels instead of [one-hot encoded labels](https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/using-categorical-data-with-one-hot-encoding), but can't tell for sure without the more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are most likely using your labels sparsely encoded, like [`0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` instead of a one-hot-encoded form.

Your solution is to choose from one of the below:

1. Use the one-hot-encoded form, i.e. transform each label to an array of length == number_of_classes. That is, for 0 you would have `[1,0,0,0,0,0,0]` for 1 you would have `[0,1,0,0,0,0,0]` etc.
2. Use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. If you use this loss functions, the OHE step is done behind the scenes and you no longer need to process your input training + validation labels.

Comment: Thank you very much Calin. This helped

Answer (score 1):

If you use one-hot-encoded for the label like [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1] you need to use `categorical_crossentropy`
but if you use sparse label like [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] you need to use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I did to_categorical on my Y array and that solved the problem.