# ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to use Keras for multi-class classification. The target variable takes 5 different values so it is not binary. When I run the code, I get     `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 5) are incompatible`. It seems I am not one-hot encoding the target variable. I wonder how I can solve this issue, where and how I do it. As you see from the code, I trying to embed categorical variables that are not binary. I followed the TensorFlow structured data classification. Any helo will be much appreciated. I want this code to work :(

```
# to check if target is in numerical or categorical and remove it
catcols=stu.select_dtypes('object').columns
numcols=stu.select_dtypes('number').columns
catcols=catcols.tolist()
numcols=numcols.tolist()
if 'target' in catcols:
    catcols.remove('target')
if 'target' in numcols:
    numcols.remove('target')

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size=0.2)
print(len(train), 'train examples')
print(len(val), 'validation examples')
print(len(test), 'test examples')

def df_to_dataset(dataframe, shuffle=True, batch_size=32):
  dataframe = dataframe.copy()
  labels = dataframe.pop('G3')
  ds = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(dataframe), labels))
  if shuffle:
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=len(dataframe))
  ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
  return ds

len_dic={}
for cat in catcols:
    len_dic[cat]=len(df[cat].unique())
feature_columns = []

# numeric cols
for numcol in numcols :
  feature_columns.append(feature_column.numeric_column(numcol))
indicator_column_names=[k for k,v in len_dic.items() if v<=2]
embcols=[c for c in catcols if c not in indicator_column_names]

# indicator_columns
for col_name in indicator_column_names:
  categorical_column = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      col_name, df[col_name].unique())
  indicator_column = feature_column.indicator_column(categorical_column)
  feature_columns.append(indicator_column)
# embedding columns
for col in embcols:
    ecol = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(col, df.col.unique())
    ecol_embedding = feature_column.embedding_column(ecol, dimension=3)
    feature_columns.append(ecol_embedding)
feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)
batch_size = 32
train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)
val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)
test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  layers.Dense(50, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(25, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dropout(.1),
  layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy,
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_ds,
          validation_data=val_ds,
          epochs=10)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I overcome "ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 7) are incompatible"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62148508/how-can-i-overcome-valueerror-shapes-none-1-and-none-7-are-incompatible)

Comment: First, thanks for trying to help. I got this error when using sparse_categorical_crossentropy the error is : UnimplementedError:  Cast string to float is not supported
  [[node sparse_categorical_crossentropy/Cast (defined at <ipython-input-46-07dfff14f1ea>:15) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_7385]
do you know why?

Comment: you need numeric targets